# Python command not working while building python docker file

Tags: python, docker, importerror

I need to run a python command while building a docker image. My docker file is as follows

```
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster
RUN /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import yaml"
```

When I run `docker build . -t hello`, I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster
---> 289f4e681a96
Step 2/2 : RUN /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import yaml"
---> Running in 4eb13a1a1e9a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Comment: You need to install the yaml module in your container before that command runs.

Comment: You might won't to run `pip` earlier to install your dependencies.

Comment: 1: pray the container has pip installed. 2: `RUN /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install pyyaml` first

Comment: pip install pyyaml is the usual solution

Comment: @DownloadPizza Why not pray for a fully working Docker image with your code directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the pyyaml package also.  You can modify your Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster
RUN /usr/local/bin/pip3 install PyYAML
RUN /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import yaml"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `yaml` module is not a part of Python's standard library.  You'll need to install it with

```
RUN python3 -m pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: This requires that 1: python2 pip is not installed and 2: that pip is on the path. `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip ...` is the safer bet

Comment: Is the full path necessary?

Comment: Depends how much you trust the container authors to not mess things up. But in a python container python should generally be on the path so probably fine without full path